# Is it a good idea to pass data between two worker threads in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I decided to split one background task in two threads. So, I have a `ScheduledExecutorService` which manages two worker threads and run them periodically every 3 seconds. They implement next two tasks:

1. Retrieve data from server
2. Some manipulations with this data

So after first thread retrieve large amount of data from the server it passes it to the second worker thread which transforms it.

But I think it is some some sort of anti-pattern because is I'll do so - one thread will depend on the other and it is bad from the Multithreaded app design point of view. Am I right or no and this solution is not bad? Any explanations especially from the general point of design will be appreciated.

Comment: Definitely not.  If the workers get to talking they'll probably revolt.

Comment: First thought - why two threads?  Why not one thread that retrieves the data, then transforms it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical `producer/consumer` example in which you can consider *the data retrieval thread* a `producer` and *the data manipulation thread* a consumer. So I do not see anything wrong in the design.

You can use an appropriate class  that implements `concurrent.BlockingQueue` to pass messages between the threads mainly from the `producer` to the `consumer`

Comment: So as I understood from your words there won't be any interdependency between two these threads?

Comment: No there should not be if you are using a `thread-safe blocking queue`. Simply the `consumer` thread will `block/wait` until data is available from the `producer` thread then process it.

Answer (score 0):

One thread. Pseudo:

```
while(true){
  dateTime start=now();
  retrieveData;
  transformData;
  dateTime end=now();
  dateTime elapsed=end-start;
  int msElapsed=dateTimeToMs(elapsed);
  if (msElapsed>0) Sleep(msElapsed);
};
```

No inter-thread comms, no synchro, no queue, no overlap, no problem.